# Access child model attributes in django templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have created model inheritance in django models like:

**models.py**

```
class Instance(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='instances')
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, name='name')
  slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name', unique=True)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)
  type = models.CharField(max_length=255, name='type', default='')
  class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_at']


class CustomInstance(Instance):
  serverCode = models.TextField(default='', blank=False)
  jsonPackageCode = models.TextField(default='', blank=False)
  type = models.CharField(max_length=255, name='type', default='custom')


class AwdInstance(Instance):
  archive = models.FileField(upload_to='archives', name='archive')
  type = models.CharField(max_length=255, name='type', default='awd')


class AwodInstance(Instance):
  archive = models.FileField(upload_to='archives', name='archive')
  type = models.CharField(max_length=255, name='type', default='awod')


class GithubInstance(Instance):
  archive = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  type = models.CharField(max_length=255, name='type', default='github')
```

How can I get child model fields in django templates like **user.instances.serverCode?**

Help me, please!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `user.instances` points only to Instance model and not to any of it's children. My first guess would be that the migration would raise an error, but if not, then there would be different related names for each child model.        
You'll have to get instances of the correct model in order to access any fields on them

Comment: is there any other way to adjust these models?                                                Actually I need to display different types of instances dynamically on the basis of type field in django templates!

Comment: You could store everything in a single model with nullable fields or have concrete models (maybe with an abstract base) and fetch from all the models but put them together in a list and use `isinstance` or `hasattr` to decide what to do